# XPath where the requirements apply to deeper nodes than the ones in resulting set

Tags: xml, xpath, webdav

In my answer to another post in SO (here: [SharePoint 2007, how to check if a folder exists in a document library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948552/sharepoint-2007-how-to-check-if-a-folder-exists-in-a-document-library/2005855#2005855)) I had to parse an XML document with structure:

```
D:multistatus
|--D:response
|----D:propstat
|-------D:prop
|----------D:displayname
|----------D:isFolder
```

Is it possible to construct an XPath statement that selects a set of such `D:response` elements that contain `D:displayname` equal to `"someName"` and `D:isFolder` is `"t"`?

I know how to do it if I select all `D:response` elements and then loop through the result set, but I believe XPath is powerful enough to do that in more delicate way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//D:response[D:propstat/D:prop/D:displayname="someName" and D:propstat/D:prop/D:isFolder="t"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it, XPath is powerful ;-) Any good resources where I could read more about general rules of constructing XPath statements?

Comment: webmonkey has xpath tutorials... w3c has full xpath spec, you can do it using web search

Comment: Shorter and more efficient: `/*/D:response[D:propstat/D:prop[D:displayname='someName' and D:isFolder='t']]`

Answer (score 2):

If `displayname` and `isFolder` can appear anywhere within `D:response`, then this should work.

```
//D:response//[D:displayname="someName" and D:isFolder="t"]
```

// means the node can appear anywhere in the hierarchy and

[...] is a predicate used to filter elements matching the given criteria.

Comment: I believe that the structure is more or less standard, since a lot of tools have been built that implement WebDAV. However, your version is shorter than the one posted by @Jimmy zhang

Comment: Didn't know it was WebDAV. There are countless ways to do this in Xpath, but Jimmys solution is definitely better as it enforces the hierarchy which can avoid a lot of headache later on :)

Answer (score 1):

A shorter and more efficient variant of @Jimmy Zhang's answer is

```
/*/D:response[D:propstat/D:prop[D:displayname='someName' and D:isFolder='t']]
```

It avoids the inefficient `//` operator (which needlessly checks the whole tree when the position of the target element is actually known).  Also it uses a nested predicate to avoid redundancy.

Comment: What exactly does `/*/` mean? Do you know some good reference manual where these constructs are explained?

Comment: `*` matches **any element**. Check out w3schools reference on XPATH syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: oh, finally got it- the first slash is the root, then you say "any element as a direct child of root node" and then you request "D:response" element. Thanks for the link!