# What is RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache internally?

Tags: .net, http, caching, httpwebrequest

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.requestcachelevel.aspx) on `RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache` doesn't explain much on the internal working of setting this with `HttpWebRequest`. Some questions I have on it:

- What cache is this refering to?

  - A [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-webclient-disable-cache/3851617#3851617) which implies it shares with Internet Explorer?
- Is this setting adding any [cache control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) headers?
- How does this compare with `NoCacheNoStore` & `Reload` which do set headers?
- If I want to ensure (as much as possible from the client side) that the content does not come from cache is this the best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question:

- `HttpWebRequest` does make use of the IE cache and `RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache` is refering to that cache.
- The setting is adding cache control headers
- Compared to `NoCacheNoStore` both avoid the cache; however, `BypassCache` will load to the cache so if you do a future request it will be there. `Reload` does similar but the headers allow proxies to return from their cache whereas `BypassCache` tells proxies to ignore their cache too.
- Yes, it is the best option ;)