# Download image from server

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

I've to download an image from the server on button click.
The code is:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;
        progressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;
        WebClient w = new WebClient();
        w.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/xxx/image.png"));
        w.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(w_OpenReadCompleted);
    }

    void w_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
        BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
        b.SetSource(e.Result);
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = b;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
    }
```

The problem which I'm facing is that for the first time the data is being downloaded from the server and shown correctly.  However, if I quit the application and again start it, it downloads the old image even if I have deleted the image from the server or changed the image. I think the image is getting cached somewhere but don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be the same as your issue:

[How do you disable caching with WebClient and Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173052/how-do-you-disable-caching-with-webclient-and-windows-phone-7)

I haven't noticed this behaviour when using the HttpWebRequest to get data. But I'am not sure about it.

Update: HttpWebRequest has by default the same behaviour but can be disabled. This blogpost is talking about the options you have:
http://www.nickharris.net/2010/10/windows-phone-7-httpwebrequest-returns-same-response-from-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to fix it.
The only change that was made is:

```
w.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/xxx/image.png?q="+Guid.NewGuid()));
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also use HttpWebRequest to download fresh data every request.  Here is a simple class which sets up the asynchronous calls

Here is a simple http client which will download data from the given uri.

```
public static class HttpClient
{
    public static void Execute(Uri uri, Action<HttpWebRequest> onrequest, Action<HttpWebResponse> onresponse)
    {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);

        onrequest(request);

        request.BeginGetResponse
        (
            result =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (request.HaveResponse)
                        onresponse((HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result));
                }
                catch { }
            },
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Using the HttpClient with your button click event you get this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).IsEnabled = false;
    progressbar.IsIndeterminate = true;

    HttpClient.Execute
    (
        new Uri(http://example.com/xxx/image.png),

        request =>
        {
            request.UserAgent = "Custom HTTP Client";
        },

        response =>
        {
            progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
            BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
            b.SetSource(response.GetResponseStream());
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = b;
            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(img);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This code will still have the caching issue. If you use the HttpWebRequest you still have to add an extra header to the request to disable caching.