# Should I disable WebClient caching?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient

WebClient.DownloadStringAsync does cache the server response.
After once getting a response from the server I get a response even without internet connection!

Is WebClient caching smart enough to determine from the server response how long to cache?
Or is it buggy and I should disable caching.

Backgound info:

Url: http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Fiddler trace:

GET /stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: file:///Applications/Install/4D0DF1F7-1481-45CA-86BE-C14FF5CCD955/Install/
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: www.ecb.europa.eu
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Mar 2012 08:54:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Linux/SUSE)
Last-Modified: Fri, 23 Mar 2012 13:31:39 GMT
ETag: "19d4e5-6a9-4bbe90b5904c0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1705
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerPOOL.www.ecb.europa.eu_HTTP=2684883628.16415.0000; path=/

...

Disabling caching via Headers does not work:

.Headers("cache-control") = "no-cache" 
.Headers("HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince") = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()

Disabling caching via appending uniqa parameter works:

"http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml" & "?MakeRequestUnique=" & Environment.TickCount

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173052/how-do-you-disable-caching-with-webclient-and-windows-phone-7

Comment: Not a duplicate: I would like to know "if" I should disable the cache and not how. I is not clear to me, what algorithm the phone  WebClient phone uses for caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrated cache isn't smart at all. So if you expect different results when querying the page, you have to bypass it. I say 'bypass' because there's no way I know of to disable it with the WebClient (I don't think it's enabled if you directly use the HttpRequest class). 
So if you want to use the WebClient, the best way is to append a random parameter to the request.

Comment: I just confirmed via a test that HttpWebRequest does not cache by default. Does anybody know how long WebClient does cache, or what makes it go to the web site again?