# DownloadStringAsync returns the same string while called multiple times

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to develop a radio app for windows phone 7.5. I made a webclient that downloads a string from remote server which contains title and other info of the song.The string then is passed to a textblock. Everything seems to be working fine but there is a little problem. The remote file that contains the string is frequently updating. So I want to keep my textblock updated aswell. I made a timer to download the string every 5 seconds and logically it should update the textblock. The problem is that it keeps downloading the same string although the remote file is updating. Why?

DownloadTitle.cs:

```
class DonwloadTitle
{
  public string ResultText { get; set; }
  public void DownloadStringTitle()
  {
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress=true;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation=true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    worker.DoWork+=worker_DoWork;
  }

  void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    WebClient HitClient = new WebClient();
    HitClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    HitClient.DownloadStringCompleted += HitClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
    HitClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://air-online2.hitfm.md/status_hitfm.xsl"));
  }

  void HitClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    ResultText = e.Result.Substring(167);
  }
}
```

I tried this algorithm in C# for windows desktop and it worked. But for windows phone not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set cache policy:

```
   RequestCachePolicy policy = new  RequestCachePolicy( RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
   HitClient.CachePolicy = policy;
```

Comment: There is no such class in C# for windows phone:(

Comment: I have found a solution.it is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173052/how-do-you-disable-caching-with-webclient-and-windows-phone-7 but your answer gave a good idea and i thank you mister. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Can you please review this question aswell? :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354864/update-song-title-in-windows-phone-background-audio-agenta