# Update Song title in windows phone background audio agent?a

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am making a radio app for windows phone 7.5. I want to play radio in the background. For that i am using windows phone background audio agent. In the agent code i nee to indicate the track and all the infor according to it. But i want to update the song title and artist name in the track declaration.The track declaration looks like this:

```
new AudioTrack(new Uri("Ring03.wma", UriKind.Relative), 
                        "Ringtone 3", 
                        "Windows Phone", 
                        "Windows Phone Ringtones", 
                        new Uri("shared/media/Ring03.jpg", UriKind.Relative)),
```

I wanted to store strings in some variables and then replace them with "Ringtone 3". So that i constantly change the value of the title string. I want to update the title every 5 seconds. So i want my media player to show to the user the track info, so that when the user changes the volume he would see the name and artist in a neat box. I tried to accomplish that but i get a error:( whic sounds like that:

Error   4   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'MyAudioPlaybackAgent.AudioPlayer.title.get'

Please help:(

AudioPlayer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio;

namespace AudioPlaybackAgent1
{
    public class AudioPlayer : AudioPlayerAgent
    {
        private static volatile bool _classInitialized;

        /// <remarks>
        /// AudioPlayer instances can share the same process. 
        /// Static fields can be used to share state between AudioPlayer instances
        /// or to communicate with the Audio Streaming agent.
        /// </remarks>
        public AudioPlayer()
        {
            if (!_classInitialized)
            {
                _classInitialized = true;
                // Subscribe to the managed exception handler
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                {
                    Application.Current.UnhandledException += AudioPlayer_UnhandledException;
                });
            }
        }

        /// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void AudioPlayer_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the playstate changes, except for the Error state (see OnError)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="player">The BackgroundAudioPlayer</param>
        /// <param name="track">The track playing at the time the playstate changed</param>
        /// <param name="playState">The new playstate of the player</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Play State changes cannot be cancelled. They are raised even if the application
        /// caused the state change itself, assuming the application has opted-in to the callback.
        /// 
        /// Notable playstate events: 
        /// (a) TrackEnded: invoked when the player has no current track. The agent can set the next track.
        /// (b) TrackReady: an audio track has been set and it is now ready for playack.
        /// 
        /// Call NotifyComplete() only once, after the agent request has been completed, including async callbacks.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnPlayStateChanged(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, PlayState playState)
        {
            switch (playState)
            {

                case PlayState.TrackEnded:
                    player.Track = GetPreviousTrack();
                    break;
                case PlayState.TrackReady:
                    player.Play();
                    break;
                case PlayState.Shutdown:
                    // TODO: Handle the shutdown state here (e.g. save state)
                    break;
                case PlayState.Unknown:

                    break;
                case PlayState.Stopped:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Paused:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Playing:
                    break;
                case PlayState.BufferingStarted:
                    break;
                case PlayState.BufferingStopped:
                    break;
                case PlayState.Rewinding:
                    break;
                case PlayState.FastForwarding:
                    break;
            }

            NotifyComplete();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the user requests an action using application/system provided UI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="player">The BackgroundAudioPlayer</param>
        /// <param name="track">The track playing at the time of the user action</param>
        /// <param name="action">The action the user has requested</param>
        /// <param name="param">The data associated with the requested action.
        /// In the current version this parameter is only for use with the Seek action,
        /// to indicate the requested position of an audio track</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// User actions do not automatically make any changes in system state; the agent is responsible
        /// for carrying out the user actions if they are supported.
        /// 
        /// Call NotifyComplete() only once, after the agent request has been completed, including async callbacks.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnUserAction(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, UserAction action, object param)
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case UserAction.Play:
                    if (player.PlayerState != PlayState.Playing)
                    {
                        track.Title = "tracktitle";
                        player.Play();
                    }
                    break;
                case UserAction.Stop:
                    player.Stop();
                    break;
                case UserAction.Pause:
                    player.Pause();
                    break;
                case UserAction.FastForward:
                    player.FastForward();
                    break;
                case UserAction.Rewind:
                    player.Rewind();
                    break;
                case UserAction.Seek:
                    player.Position = (TimeSpan)param;
                    break;
                case UserAction.SkipNext:
                    player.Track = GetNextTrack();
                    break;
                case UserAction.SkipPrevious:
                    AudioTrack previousTrack = GetPreviousTrack();
                    if (previousTrack != null)
                    {
                        player.Track = previousTrack;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            NotifyComplete();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Implements the logic to get the next AudioTrack instance.
        /// In a playlist, the source can be from a file, a web request, etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The AudioTrack URI determines the source, which can be:
        /// (a) Isolated-storage file (Relative URI, represents path in the isolated storage)
        /// (b) HTTP URL (absolute URI)
        /// (c) MediaStreamSource (null)
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>an instance of AudioTrack, or null if the playback is completed</returns>
        private AudioTrack GetNextTrack()
        {
            // TODO: add logic to get the next audio track

            AudioTrack track = null;

            // specify the track

            return track;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Implements the logic to get the previous AudioTrack instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The AudioTrack URI determines the source, which can be:
        /// (a) Isolated-storage file (Relative URI, represents path in the isolated storage)
        /// (b) HTTP URL (absolute URI)
        /// (c) MediaStreamSource (null)
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>an instance of AudioTrack, or null if previous track is not allowed</returns>
        private AudioTrack GetPreviousTrack()
        {
            // TODO: add logic to get the previous audio track

            AudioTrack track = null;

            // specify the track

            return track;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called whenever there is an error with playback, such as an AudioTrack not downloading correctly
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="player">The BackgroundAudioPlayer</param>
        /// <param name="track">The track that had the error</param>
        /// <param name="error">The error that occured</param>
        /// <param name="isFatal">If true, playback cannot continue and playback of the track will stop</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method is not guaranteed to be called in all cases. For example, if the background agent 
        /// itself has an unhandled exception, it won't get called back to handle its own errors.
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnError(BackgroundAudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, Exception error, bool isFatal)
        {
            if (isFatal)
            {
                Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                NotifyComplete();
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the agent request is getting cancelled
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Once the request is Cancelled, the agent gets 5 seconds to finish its work,
        /// by calling NotifyComplete()/Abort().
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnCancel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

AudioStreamer.cs

```
using Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio;
using System.Windows.Media;
namespace AudioStreamAgent1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A background agent that performs per-track streaming for playback
    /// </summary>
    public class AudioTrackStreamer : AudioStreamingAgent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a new track requires audio decoding
        /// (typically because it is about to start playing)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="track">
        /// The track that needs audio streaming
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="streamer">
        /// The AudioStreamer object to which a MediaStreamSource should be
        /// attached to commence playback
        /// </param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// To invoke this method for a track set the Source parameter of the AudioTrack to null
        /// before setting  into the Track property of the BackgroundAudioPlayer instance
        /// property set to true;
        /// otherwise it is assumed that the system will perform all streaming
        /// and decoding
        /// </remarks>
        protected override void OnBeginStreaming(AudioTrack track, AudioStreamer streamer)
        {
            //TODO: Set the SetSource property of streamer to a MSS source

            NotifyComplete();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the agent request is getting cancelled
        /// The call to base.OnCancel() is necessary to release the background streaming resources
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnCancel()
        {
            base.OnCancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background Audio agent is not a right choice for a radio streaming, you should use Background Streaming agent instead.
There are some good samples with mostly complete apps for audio streaming: [Streaming MP3 player in WP7](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Streaming_MP3_player_in_WP7) and [Background audio overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You can set the track name via this code:

```
  var player = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance;
  player.Track = "new track name";
```

Comment: mmmm that didnt help me either :(

Comment: when i try to set the track name by the code you sent me it gives a null reference exception. It is like this property is read-only , but its actually not. And i dont understand what's the deal here.

Comment: I have found two methods in the track property called BeginEdit() and EndEdit() ,what do they do?

Comment: It means that you have no active instance of BackgroundAudioPlayer.

Comment: Ok you gave me an example with those posts. But could you give another one please. I am going craz right now:s

Comment: Show more code of your background agent and how do you start it.

Comment: I have edited the question with codes. I start the player in the MainPage.xaml.cs with a simple line BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play()

Comment: well i guess this challenge is not completed:(

Comment: it is ok fellow programmer :) i will try to find a solution and if i do i will share it.Thanks anyway.You are a great man:)