# How to clear windows mobile 8 url cache

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webclient

Hi im facing a problem in my windows 8 mobile app.Im sending a request to the server using WebClient to pull the details.I have an on demand refresh feature available in the app where the user can refresh the details when ever he wants.The problem i face is the new details are not being updated.I have tried some of the solutions mentioned by adding ?nocache at the end of the url.But this solution will not help me because im actually passing values through this url to a server, after processing these values at the server side they will redirect the response to "http://mysitezz.com/myfolder/files/details546546546546.xml". So if i append ?nocache i will get error response. Also i have tried adding header in Webclient that didnt work too

```
     WebClient wctrans = new WebClient();

 //  wctrans.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.LastModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
    wctrans.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(UpdateLocalDB);
      wctrans.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(calculatedURL), nextItem.AccountNo);
```

Is there any way to solve this issue? Im pretty new to windows phone app developement.Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't the caching issue be on the server? WebClient shouldn't be caching anything on the device, but the server may be caching the responses.

Comment: Im using the same webservice in android and ios as well, there it works with out any problem.The issue is happening only in wp8

Comment: have you tried to add a random param to your url. just like:calculatedURL + "&random=" + aRandomNumber

Comment: Yes, But im getting error as response.The request im sending is similar to this  http://blahblah.com/myfolder/details.jsp?skuid=456789097&accountid=9879867456746&from_date=15-Jan-2014&to_date=14-Feb-2014 . If i add anything at the end of the url will throw an error,so  i think appending wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve this problem from the client side.Finally i had  force the server team to make changes at their end.Acutally the problem was happening in ios and android too

Answer (score 0):

as per this article [C# WebClient disable cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache/3872216#3872216) , use HttpRequest object instead of WebClient

Comment: But the OP says that it will return an error from his server. so appending wont work.

Comment: @playmaker420, did you try the second solution? which is this:    WebClient wctrans = new WebClient();
 wctrans.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()

Comment: @KirtiSagar yes please see the question i have added headers.  wctrans.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.LastModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();     wctrans.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(); Tried both.

Comment: @playmaker420, pls try the above solution, I hope this helps