# WebClient.DownloadStringAsync URL not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

I've got an issue about webclient on windowsphone 8.
I've hit an API use webclient on my code.

```
    public void LoadData(bool refresh)
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.xxxx.com/getQuestion"));
    }

    public void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject deserCustomers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        foreach (var cust in deserCustomers.data)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(cust.title);
            int length = cust.question.Length;
            string subquestion;
            if (length > 100) { subquestion = cust.question.Substring(0, 100); }
            else { subquestion = cust.question; }
            _questiondata.Add(new QuestionItem() { Title = cust.title, Question_Str = subquestion, Slug = cust.slug });
        }

        IsLoading = false;
    }
```

It's work for the first time and the data is exactly same as web. But when the web update with new question, and I try to call method LoadData for the second time, the data not same as web. the new update question on web does not appear in my apps (windows phone).
What should I do, Is there any cache that make my result not updated like on web?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like a caching-related issue. Maybe this SO Article can help you: [Disable Caching in WebClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache)

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht thank you. I added random variable into url and IT WORKS! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a help and it Solved. try this:

```
public void LoadData(bool refresh)
{
    IsLoading = true;
    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted;
    Random random = new Random();
    webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.xxxx.com/getQuestion?random="+ random.Next().ToString()));
}
```

Comment: This looks nice in the first place, but it is still possible to have repeating numbers, since `Random.Next()` might produce the same value thousands of times. Alternatively you could just count some integer-variable.

Comment: thank you for ur concern @PatrikEckebrecht .
but where is the cache location? server side or client side

Comment: This caching is done by operating system. The typical practice is to add the DateTime.Now.Ticks, just to avoid random number collision.