# WebClient().DownloadString() returning old data

Tags: c#, php, webclient

I am using this code to get the return string from URL

```
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
response = webClient.DownloadString("http://somesite.com/code.php");
Console.Write(response);
```

the `code.php` looks like this

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('code.txt');
echo $data;
?>
```

The problem is when I change the contents of the `code.txt` file, the `webClient.DownloadString()` method returns the old contents of the `code.txt` file. When I open the URL `http://somesite.com/code.php` in a browser it works perfectly fine.

Any solutions will be appreciated!

My question seems to be duplicated but I don't really understand what is said here: [C# WebClient disable cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache)

If anyone could explain and provide some example code it would be great!

Comment: i do not really understand the answer to that. any sample code?

Comment: There are a lot of useful hints in the answers to the question I've mentioned. Have you tried to disable caching in `webclient` or even switch to `HttpWebRequest` instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try disabling the cache on the WebClient

```
webClient.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

[MSDN Documentation on WebClient Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cachepolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)