# Batch script to copy the contents of a website to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I need to find a way using batch to copy the contents of a website to a variable.

My current code is:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/piauth/wordfinderpcversion/master/sample-v1')"`) do set variable=%%a
```

It works, but when I run it in a loop,

```
:st

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/piauth/wordfinderpcversion/master/sample-v1')"`) do set variable=%%a

echo %variable%

goto st
```

and change the content of the GitHub file from "1" to "2", it doesn't echo "2" and instead continues to echo "1". Any idea about how to fix this? I'm open to using a different command to get the web page content's to a variable as long as it doesn't involve any third party software.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: To be sure that the variable is undefined on each iteration of the loop, you could insert a line `Set "variable="` before the `For` line, _(which I would change to ```For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/piauth/wordfinderpcversion/master/sample-v1')"')Do Set "variable=%%A"
```)_. I would also change `echo %variable%` to `Echo(%variable%` to prevent any `ECHO is off` message, should there be no content or a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the cache on the WebClient:

```
webClient.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

(see: [WebClient().DownloadString() returning old data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403130/webclient-downloadstring-returning-old-data))