# How to make clientdownloadasync download a new file when it has changed, instead of the cached

Tags: vb.net

So I am writing an AutoUpdate tool for my program. So far all has worked good except when I update the file on my site, it still downloads the old version for a while. How can I make it always download the new file instead of (I guess its a cached version). Do I need to change something on my site, or can I do it within vb?

Here is the code for downloading:

```
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadCompleted
client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://www.redpoisonjb.com/timertracker.exe"), "Timer Tracker.exe")
```

Comment: Strange as it should be replaced ... The old file should be replaced with the new one...

Comment: @Codexer : Yeah, caching shouldn't apply to files...

Comment: Have you tried a cachebuster? You could add `"?" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()` to the URL.

Comment: Try checking this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache

Comment: @AndrewMorton Trying that now, thanks!