# WebClient consecutive download produces unrealistic download speed

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, download, webclient

I am trying to do consecutive downloads, from a router hard drive (with certain IP address), one after the other until a Toggle switch is disabled. The first download happens normally an it produces a realistic average download speed (Approx. 60 to 80 Mbps). However after the first download, the adjacent downloads might produce average download speeds as 2Gbps, 5Gbps or even Infinity. I have tried with different file sizes but with almost the same result. Here is the code that I am using for the consecutive download test.

```
Function SpeedTest()
    Do
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        wc.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")

        wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("file://192.XXX.XX.X/Download_Files/1gb.test"), tmp)

        While wc.IsBusy
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While  

        For i As Integer = 1 To 100
            Thread.Sleep(10)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
    Loop Until Toggle1.Checked = False
    Return 0
End Function

Private tmp = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "1gb.test")
```

I believe that the first downloaded file is restored from the cache files for the adjacent downloads. Not sure, if this is true. (I could see that 1GB file download finishes within less than a second.) But if so, how can I remove the cache files to produce realistic download speeds?

Comment: You _**SHOULD NOT**_ be using `Application.DoEvents()` to keep your UI responsive! See: [**Keeping your UI Responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Comment: `DownloadFileAsync` and its related [**`DownloadFileCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) exist for the sole purpose of being able to perform downloads in the background.

Comment: I do have `wc.DownloadFileCompleted` and `wc.DownloadProgressChanged` for monitoring the timeout and the download speed calculation. But the issue happens when I use the download function in a loop. Also, are you recommending to use `Application.Run()` instead of `Application.DoEvents()`?

Comment: @ArunKumar what?

Comment: No I dont. `Application.Run()` is for when yoy create the first form and it is automatically called by the framework.

Comment: You shouldn't use anything that makes your application _**appear**_ responsive. The only way to actually keep an application responsive _**properly**_ is to do all heavy work in a background thread and let the UI thread work on its own (by "heavy" I mean work that takes so long that the UI freezes, smaller/faster operations are still fine to execute on the UI thread).

Comment: Instead of using a loop for this just start a new download every time it gets to `DownloadFileCompleted`. In there you can also verify if `Toggle1` is checked or not.

Comment: @djv Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Visual Vincent I have tried that. Did not make any difference.

Comment: It does make a difference: it doesn't freeze your UI thread, so you won't have to constantly use `Application.DoEvents()` in the wrong way. -- As for your actual issue you could try disabling cache. Try the two code blocks in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache

Comment: Where it says `RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache` you can try replacing with `RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore` if `BypassCache` doesn't work.

Comment: @VisualVincent Sorry, you misunderstood me. I was referring to verifying `Toggle1` being checked in the `DownloadFileCompleted` didn't make any difference. Not about `Application.DoEvents()`. I have also tried both `BypassCache` and `NoCacheNoStore`. Both didn't work. It is suggested in that thread that to use Sockets (`HttpRequest`) instead of WebClient. If there is no solution for the WebClient cache issue, I would try that.

Comment: Well you're not supposed to use _**a loop**_ to check `Toggle1` because then you occupy the UI thread once again. The whole point of using the `DownloadFileCompleted` event is that it is raised every time a file has been completely downloaded. Only then will you ever need to check if you are to download more or not, so a simple `If Toggle1.Checked = True Then` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tests, and checking out [C# WebClient disable cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache), HttpWebRequest (In my case, FileWebRequest) is more helpful in controlling the downloading and uploading files. Also after controlling the buffer size, the tests made more realistic values compared to download/upload done through normal method. Also, while using *WebClient*, the download routine had a buffer size of 64KB and the upload had a buffer size of 8KB. In order to produce a rate closer to the windows download speed, the buffer size had to be 1/100th of the file size. Repeated download still didn't produce the same result. But if you change the buffer size to 1/1000th of the file size from the second try onwards, then repeated download rates would look similar. Here is the code that I used for downloading.

```
oRequest = CType(FileWebRequest.Create("file://192.XXX.XX.X/Download_Files/1gb.test"), FileWebRequest)
oRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")
oResponse = CType(oRequest.GetResponse, WebResponse)
responseStream = oResponse.GetResponseStream()
buffer = New Byte(FileLen(tmp) / 100) {}
fs = New FileStream(tmp, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
Do
    read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop Until read = 0
responseStream.Close()
fs.Flush()
fs.Close()
responseStream.Close()
oResponse.Close()
buffer = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to continuously download files, and allow the toggle to cancel download

```
Private sw As New Stopwatch()
Private wc As WebClient
Private tmp = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "1gb.test")

Private Sub startDownload()
    If wc IsNot Nothing Then
        wc.Dispose()
    End If
    wc = New WebClient()
    wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)")
    wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    wc.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("admin", "admin")
    AddHandler wc.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf downloadProgressChanged
    AddHandler wc.DownloadDataCompleted, AddressOf downloadDataCompleted
    sw.Reset()
    sw.Start()
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("file://192.XXX.XX.X/Download_Files/1gb.test"), tmp)
End Sub

Private Sub cancelDownload()
    If wc IsNot Nothing AndAlso wc.IsBusy Then
        wc.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Toggle1.CheckedChanged
    If Toggle1.Checked Then
        startDownload()
    Else
        cancelDownload()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub downloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(Sub() Me.Text = e.ProgressPercentage)
End Sub

Private Sub downloadDataCompleted(sender As Object, e As DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
    sw.Stop()
    Dim message = If(e.Cancelled, "Operation was cancelled!", "Operation completed!")
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        message &= Environment.NewLine & "Exception: " & e.Error.Message
    End If
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(tmp)
    Dim sizeInBytes = fi.Length
    Dim durationInSeconds = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000
    message &= String.Format("Downloaded {0} bytes in {1} seconds ({2} Bps)", sizeInBytes, durationInSeconds, sizeInBytes / durationInSeconds)
    ' do what you want with message, if anything
    If Not e.Cancelled Then
        startDownload()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It does the continuous download as the code that I provided earlier. However, the issue still exists when you are downloading the same file from the network drive. It retrieves the cache data instead of downloading again from the drive. So, the download speed shows some random value such as 2Gbps etc.

Comment: How about if you delete `IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, "1gb.test")` when each file is completed?

Comment: Tried that as well. Didn't work. I could see that the file gets deleted from the Temp folder and when the "Download Progress:" message appears (the text appears when entering downloadprogresschanged), the file instantly reappears in the Temp folder. I have tried for different size files: 10MB, 100MB, 1GB, all producing the same output.

Comment: What if you generate a new name each time? Using `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

Comment: Are you referring to `tmp2 = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".test")`. I tried this and still have the cache issue.