# Powershell download page in 0 milliseconds

Tags: powershell

I have a strange problem with my script in powershell, I want to examine the average time of downloading page. I write script which fires frequently. But sometimes my script returns result 0, which means it downloads site in 0 ms. If i modified my script to save whole site to the file when the download time is about 0ms it doesn't saves anything. And I'm interesting if I do something wrong, or powershell function isn't too accurate to count such "small" times.

ps. other "good" results are about 4-9 ms.

Here is a part of my script which responds to count the download time:

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
$PageDownload = $Request.DownloadString("mypage.com")
$TimeTaken = ((Get-Date) - $StartTime).TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Date` should be as precise as the system clock is.

There could be web caching going on.  Unfortunately, disabling caching for WebClient is not possible, from [what I see elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812089/c-sharp-webclient-disable-cache).  The "do it right" method is to construct your own Http request with the TcpClient class, but that's also [pretty complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109695/how-do-i-create-an-http-request-manually-in-net).

One easy way to make sure you're not being cached is to put an arbitrary value as a GET request.  It's a hack, but it is often enough to fool a cache.  So, instead of:

```
"http://mypage.com"
```

You use:

```
"http://mypage.com?someUnusedValueName=$([System.Environment]::TickCount)"
```